# Prevenir submit do form, mas permitir outras ações ao teclar enter num input

Tags: jquery, formulário

Tenho um `input text` dentro de um `form`, entretanto não quero que o `form` seja submetido ao teclar <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. O código abaixo funciona, mas se eu descomentar o `alert` o `form` é submetido mesmo tendo as duas linhas abaixo. Alguém sabe me explicar o porquê?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtPesquisaServidor').keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            //alert('enter!');
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Estou usando jQuery 1.6.2

EDIT 1
O `alert` é só ilustrativo, ao teclar <kbd>ENTER</kbd> o `input` terá o mesmo comportamento do click do botão https://jsfiddle.net/o0mkjnwk/

EDIT 2
consegui! Se eu fosse utilizar o `alert` teria que setar o `timeout` ou utilizar o `stop()` para que o código não se confundisse, enviando assim o `form` (o que não era o desejado). O problema, na verdade, não existe sem o `alert`. Acabei de colocar o meu código original para testar e funcionou sem problemas.

Código funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/o0mkjnwk/1/

Agradeço a todos que contribuíram.

Comment: Em que browser estás a testar? Ter ou não `alert();` não deve fazer diferença de comportamento. Podes fazer um jsFiddle que mostre o comportamento?

Comment: Sugeriram usar uma versão mais recente do plugin e trocar o keydown por .on('keypress'). Segue https://jsfiddle.net/ysj6uk54/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito não ser a melhor solução, mas funcionou aqui, usando o

> stop();

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txtPesquisaServidor').keydown(function(event){
      if(event.keyCode == 13) {
          alert('enter');
          event.preventDefault();
          stop();
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: testei aqui e funcionou na versão do plugin que estou utilizando também, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Utilize `setTimeout` para resolver.

Problema: Você está utilizando o evento certo para capturar a tecla **(keydown)**, o problema está no **alert**, quando ele é disparado, o seu controle perde o foco, e neste momento você ainda não retornou falso para a ação do evento. Com isso é disparado o outro evento **(keyup)** e o retorno falso se perde, com isso é feito o *submit*.

Use:

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("enter"); }, 10);
```

Comment: o problema é que na verdade o alert é só para teste, o que eu vou fazer ao teclar enter é um $.get() em outra página, que vai fazer uma consulta no banco, salvar o retorno na sessão e logo após o get a página recarrega mostrando os dados da sessão. É o que o botão que acompanha o input já faz https://jsfiddle.net/o0mkjnwk/

Comment: tente usar sempre o console.log para fazer esse tipo de teste, ele vai influenciar bem menos seus testes, pois não vai disparar eventos.